# Set value to ClientPeoplePicker

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, rest, jsom

I need to set value into a `ClientPeoplePicker,` my list save the user as a `SPUserField`, I already get the id from the list.

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {
    var controlName = fieldName;
    var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
    var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
    var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];

    peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);
    spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

    //disable the field
    spPeoplePicker.SetEnabledState(false);

    //hide the delete/remove use image from the people picker
    $('.sp-peoplepicker-delImage').css('display','none');
}
```

Credit to: http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/sp2013-setting-people-picker-value-in-newform-aspx/

Alternatively you could use something like the [SPUtility library](http://sputility.codeplex.com), which simplifies the process to:

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Display Name').SetValue('User Account');
```

http://sputility.codeplex.com